element by element matrix multiplication on polyBasis- MATLAB
on MATLAB I am trying to use polyBasis on a bunch of vector matrices, but i want to require that all multiplication is element by element. is this possible, if so, how? specifically, i have this
V = polyBasis('canonical',3,3));  Vectors=V(x,y,z); 
where all the matrices in Vectors are gotten by element by element multiplication. example xyz should be x.*y.*z. because all my vectors are column vectors
i tried to use ndBasis, and defined my basis function as
F= @(x) [x,x.^3],  V = ndBasis(F,F,F), Vector= V(x,y,z); 
but the dimensionality didn't match what my answer was supposed to be, so i knew something was off.
